# Actionscript 3 : MovieClip control

Tags: actionscript

Hello I have a SWF clip that I got from a friend. the code looks like this:

```
[Embed(source="assets/gorilla_run.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]private   var gorillaRun:Class;

public var loader:Loader = new Loader();
private var movie:MovieClip= new MovieClip;

loader.loadBytes(new gorillaRun());
movie.addChild(loader);

stage.addChild(movie);
```

I would like to access the frames of this movieclip so that I can control its action. There are many frames to this SWF however when I use this command:

> trace(movie.totalframes);

I get "1" as my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get number of frames in the container (`movie`). When you make this `movie.addChild(loader);`, you do not insert timeline from `gorilla_run.swf` to the `movie`. If you want to get total farmes try this:

```
trace(MovieClip(loader.contentLoaderInfo.content).totalFrames);
```